# Old jQuery AJAX-call

Tags: jquery

My problem is that I have an function that's should do an AJAX-call and then print the result. I can see that it does the call, but does not print the callback correctly. How would I do this the right way?
FYI; si and $id is defined by earlier in the process and does not affect the call.

```
var url = 'content/si.php';
var type = 'html';
var params = { 'id': si, 'user': <?php echo $id;?> };
var callback = function(data) {
 jQuery('#si').html(data);
}
jQuery.get(url, params, callback, url);
```

Comment: What's `url` doing in the call twice?

Comment: ^^ That's an error, the callback is the last argument, except for a datatype, which I'm guessing `url` is not

Comment: Pfft! Stupid me, of course that would generate an error...